# Start Google Navigation from another Activity without setting a location

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, android-intent

This is probably really stupid of me but how do I start google navigation WITHOUT setting a location as a lot of issues seem to come from... When I try to do this it actually starts to run Google Navigation but then just keeps restarting the Activity... Essentially I was it to run just like when you click on Navigation like you would from a home screen... So with the list of destinations etc... I presume this is a different activity maybe? I've no idea, the intent I'm using is below,

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.driveabout.app.NavigationActivity");
    getContext().startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I've been looking for over a day now and still can't find it... This is ridiculous!

Comment: This is ridiculous... What on earth is that intent to start Navigation from the menu?!?! It's not a standard MAIN intent as it's part of the maps activity.... God knows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found what Activity it is that needs starting!!!

```
  Intent i = new Intent();  
i.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.driveabout.app.DestinationActivity");
    startActivity(i);
```